# Can I get the names of the asserts if they happen in Qt? Console Application

Tags: c++, qt, logging, crash, assert

I have a long running console application written in `C++ (Qt)`. If an `assert` happens - my application crashes very bad. 
So I need to know what assert is failed. I need to know this because I have to find and fix the buggy part of the code.
How can I achieve this? I don't want my application to crash, but if crashes by failed asserts - I want to know what's wrong and where. Thanks. :)
PS: Can I `log` the assert name and the place when app crashes?

PS2: The asserts that happens are internal e.g. Qt's.

Comment: All asserts should have a descriptive text that is printed when the assertion fails. Just look in the source for that text.

Comment: When the app crashes no text is outputted. Or at least I don't know where it should be outputted. I use Debian and the application is a console.

Comment: You can check the systemlog at `/var/log/messages`.

Comment: thanks man, I found it some of the `log` files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can redirect the output to a file using command-line parameters

```
2>&1 | tee ~/console.txt
```

This will copy stderr and stdout to a txt file. Q_ASSERTS are printed to stderr so you should be able to see the output now and diagnose the problem

Comment: Where should I execute this command? Out of the program - in terminal - or from the main function?

Comment: @DonAngeloAnnoni: It's not a command, it's what you enter in the terminal after the command to start your program.